# Github Copy repository content to another repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

Our situation is like this, we have 2 repositories. One for live and one for dev.
Both repositories have different webhooks setup to different remote servers.

Question is how do I copy content from Dev repository to Live repository the right way?
Can I do it in Github interface?

thanks

Comment: I'd guess you want to get the changes from the dev repo be replayed on the live repo, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit hacky, but assuming your are pushing from local repos to a remote of the staging repo, can't you push to a remote for the production or follow a more pull request workflow if that is your process? You could probably also create a patch from the dev changes, but I don't know if you can apply the patch directly to the production github repository.

If you are coming at it fresh (with no local repository of your own), I suppose you could clone the dev repo locally, set up a remote for the new local repository to the production repository, then push to its master.